# Saving int in Unity using playerprefs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 3 ints that I need to save when the player quits the application. I want to save them using playerprefs and I need them to be able to be changed by other scripts during runtime. Can anyone give a code example of how to save with playerprefs and how to update the save when the ints are changed?

Comment: So... what from [the official documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) did you try?  There are plenty of tutorials for these basics. This is not Google

Comment: I just want a single code example. Unity documentation will tell you to refer to other docs and make you watch  videos and probably still not be very helpful

Comment: It's rare that the Unity docs actually gives a code example. I really wish they would on all their pages

Comment: I see a example in the docs. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.SetInt.html

Comment: There is an example there, thanks. I didn't look on the set int page I was looking on the main playerprefs page theres no examples there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You save like this

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Health", 100);
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Mana", 10);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

If you want to update the values, just do the same.
To get a int from playerprefs, just do

```
PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Health")
```

Comment: Thanks, so I'm guessing in the GetInt I can put a number there to change it after "health"? Or do I use SetInt again to do that?

Comment: You change it by calling SetInt again.

Comment: @RedDragon2001 If the function worked that way then you would be getting and setting at the same time, which I can't think of when that would ever be a good idea. If you're setting the value, then you already have it and don't need to get it. Likewise, if you're getting a value, then you don't currently have it so why set the value