# How to save Playerprefs to this case (Newbie)

Tags: c#, database, unity-game-engine

edit: I want to be more clear maybe I don't explain it good, apologies.
this is for an android game
about a script that switches the character's icon (gameobject) only (not the character itself)
when load or close the game, I need that icon to stay as the user chooses.

can I save and call player prefs in this(same) script?

---

here is the script:

```
using System.Collections;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class characterselection : MonoBehaviour
{

```
// referenses to controlled game objects
public GameObject avatar1, avatar2, avatar3;

// variable contains which avatar is on and active
int whichAvatarIsOn = 1;


// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

    // enable first avatar and disable another one
    avatar1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    avatar2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    avatar3.gameObject.SetActive(false);

    
}

// public method to switch avatars by pressing UI button
public void SwitchAvatar()
{

    // processing whichAvatarIsOn variable
    switch (whichAvatarIsOn)
    {

        // if the first avatar and third is on
        case 1:

            // then the second avatar is on now
            whichAvatarIsOn = 2;

            // disable the first  and third one anable the second one
            avatar1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            avatar2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            avatar3.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            break;

        // if the second and first avatar is on
        case 2:

            // then the third  is on now
            whichAvatarIsOn = 3;

            // disable the second and first one and anable the third one
            avatar1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            avatar2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            avatar3.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            break;


        // if the third and second avatar is on
        case 3:

            // then the first avatar is on now
            whichAvatarIsOn = 1;

            // disable the second and first one and anable the third one
            avatar1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            avatar2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            avatar3.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            break;
    }

}
```

}

Thank you for your time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving int in Unity using playerprefs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50658047/saving-int-in-unity-using-playerprefs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PlayerPrefs can only save string, int or float. If you want to save custom data you'll have to write your own parser and save to local file via File.WriteAllBytes or something similar.

As of right now you may save your whichAvatarIsOn with PlayerPrefs.SetInt() and PlayerPrefs.Save(), and on game restart load it with PlayerPrefs.GetInt().

EDIT:

Unity's docs will explain much better than me: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

Anyway, I'll give you the short version:

PlayerPrefs class saves data to a file somewhere on your device (the folder\path is different based on your app name and what OS you're using). To save data you specify a Key (which is a string parameter that is the ID of the value you're saving), and then specify the value to save. So, for example, if I wanted to save whichAvatarIsOn I'd call:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MyIdForThisParameter",whichAvatarIsOn);
```

And after that

```
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

The reason why you need to call Save() is because Save() effectively writes all values to file, while SetInt() only tells the PlayerPrefs that there would be some data to change when saving. And this is done because, if you were setting lots of data, saving to file each time would take significantly longer.

Once you've done this, you basically have your int on a file. So, when you need it, you just load it from file:

```
int someInt = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MyIdForThisParameter");
```

So you just pass the Key you used to save the file.

But what happens if you never saved "MyIdForThisParameter" in the first place?

Just add a default value to the call:

```
int someInt = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MyIdForThisParameter",0);
```

So if you've never saved that specific ID, the program would assign 0 as default.

As I've stated before: please note that you can only save int, float or string. You can't save complicated types like Vector3 or Quaternion. Just those 3 types.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer, I'm a newbie with coding and I copied this script from a tutorial and would like to know how to save playerprefs in this kind of situation. I mean where/when to save and where/when to load.

Comment: Editing the answer to better match your needs.

Comment: thank you so much for explaining to me that, I tried my best but I can't make it work, I'm sure I did some mistakes, I understand when to save and load, but I still don't get how to use it in this specific script. btw thank you for your effort

Comment: Pastebin link to maybe make this more clearer: https://pastebin.com/KpbFMJWu

Comment: hello, thank you for the idea, I tried it, but kinda my switch character stops working, staying at the default character :(, I really don't know where to place the command properly to their right place. I agree  this specific  script is not easy for me (at the moment I'm learning)

Comment: After a lot of practicing with your example, I figured out how to make this happen, thank you so much